# magento 2 admin how to edit table row with ko (knockout) like customer grid?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, dashboard

I created a custom grid, but I need to update the data using the grid interface using ko (knockout) JS, as in the customer grid
[image]

Created custom grid table using https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/code/Webkul/Grid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/grid_record_grid_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Grid record list UI Component
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_Grid
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                   <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </selectionsColumn>
       <column name="title">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
           <settings>
               <editor>
                   <validation>
                       <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                   </validation>
                   <editorType>text</editorType>
               </editor>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="content" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Content</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="is_active" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Webkul\Grid\Model\Status</item>
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Active</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="publish_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="update_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Time</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Webkul\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> app/code/Webkul/Grid/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/inlineEdit.php

```
<?php
namespace Webkul\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class inlineEdit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory
     */
    protected $gridFactory;

    /** @var JsonFactory  */
    protected $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * inlineEdit constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->gridFactory = $gridFactory;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $error = false;
        $messages = [];

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
            $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
            if (!count($postItems)) {
                $messages[] = __('Please correct the data sent.');
                $error = true;
            } else {
                foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $gridId) {
                    $grid = $this->gridFactory->create()->load($gridId);
                    try {
                        $grid->setData(array_merge($grid->getData(), $postItems[$gridId]));
                        $grid->save();
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $messages[] = $this->getErrorWithGridId(
                            $grid,
                            __($e->getMessage())
                        );
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param $grid
     * @param $errorText
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getErrorWithGridId($grid, $errorText)
    {
        return '[Grid ID: ' . $grid->getId() . '] ' . $errorText;
    }
}
```

[You can check cms module as an example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml#L103)

This is tested 2.3:
[image]

Comment: it works fine,  thanks